# Installing activity-browser - progressbar error

Tags: brightway

I am trying to install the activity-browser for brightway2 on Mac OS X. In the terminal and in my `b2-python` directoy, I write:

```
bin/pip install https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/activity-browser/get/2.0.zip
```

The installation starts nicely with downloading and checking the required packages. For `progessbar-ipython` however, I get an error an the installation stops:

```
File "/private/var/folders/7h/4zl3jkyd4dzgc464d3ljvv7h0000gn/T/pip-build-m1_3y3zc/progressbar-ipython/progressbar/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from compat import *
ImportError: No module named 'compat'
```

I have learned that the error comes from support for python 2.4 only, as described here: https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar/issues/28 , and here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=209444

Unfortunately, I don't get it installed. Admitted, I am not very familiar with manually installing packages. Attempts with replacing the cached version with a corrected one as described in the links have failed so far.

Do you have any ideas and suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Best wishes, Niklas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't activated the right environment. I assume you have followed the [installation instructions](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/installation.html#mac-os-x). If so, you need to make sure to activate with brightway2 environment with something like `source ~/bw2-python/bin/activate bw2`.

`progessbar-ipython` hasn't been a dependency for a long time. I guess the development versions of bw2-* should be official releases instead of `devX`, as this is just causing problems.

Comment: Jep, I was in the wrong environment. Thanks a lot - now it work's!